# Using the limit definition of the derivative to find where a function $g(x) = x|x|$ is differentiable.

Tags: calculus

Using the limit definition of the derivative to find where a function $$g(x) = x|x|$$ is differentiable.

By use of the limit definition of the derivative find where $g(x)$ is differentiable, what the derivative of $g(x)$ is where the derivative is defined and the type of any non-differentiable points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

- for $x>0 \quad g(x)=x^2$
- for $x<0 \quad g(x)=-x^2$

which are both differentiable, therefore we only need to check the case $x=0$, that is by definition

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Compute the difference Quotient $$\frac{(h+x_0)|x_0+h|-x_0|x_0|}{h}$$
In the case that $$x_0+h\geq 0$$ and $$x_0\geq 0$$ we get
$$\frac{(h+x_0)^2-x_0^2}{h}=h+2x_0$$
In the case that $$x_0+h\geq 0$$ and $$x_0<0$$ then we have
$$\frac{(h+x_0)^2+x_0^2}{h}$$
Ine cas that $$x_0+h<0$$ and $$x_0\geq 0$$ we get
$$\frac{-(x_0+h)^2+x_0^2}{h}$$
From here we get $$-h-2x_0$$
And in the last case we get
$$\frac{(x_0+h)^2+x_0^2}{h}$$

Comment: $\frac{(h+x_0)|x_0+h|-x_0|x_0|}{h}$ ????